# Parse data from arduino serial using python

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to parse data from an arduino using pySerial in order to attribute each value into variable use for tKinter GUI app.

For that I am trying to get data from the arduino and to attribute each parsed value into float or complex (text + num) variable. For that my first test was to use if condition for each data type but I don't know if it's adapted way and my code like that doesn't work.

```py
# Get value from the data serial arduino braud 9600
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem14201', 9600, timeout=3, writeTimeout=0)
data = ser.read_all()

Analog value=0.0
Voltage=0 # int
temp=0.0
EC=0.0
TemperatureB=0.0
HumidityB=0.0
pHvalue=0.0
extractorstatement="NULL"
lightstatement="NULL"
intractorstatement="NULL"
FANstatement="NULL"
date="NULL" # as sting

def DataReaderThread():
    while True:
        currentLineRead = ser.readline()
        print(currentLineRead)
        currentLineReadName=reading.split(":",0)
        currentLineReadValue=reading.split(":",1)
        if currentLineReadName="b\'Analog value":
            analogValue=currentLineReadValue
        elif currentLineReadName="b\'Voltage":
            VoltageEcSensor=currentLineReadValue
        elif currentLineReadName="b\'temp":
            tempWaterSensor=currentLineReadValue
        elif currentLineReadName="b\'EC":
            if currentLineReadValue="No solution!\r\n\'":
                EcSensorValue=0.0
            else:
                EcSensorValue=currentLineReadValue
        elif currentLineReadName="b\'TemperatureB":
            TemperatureB=currentLineReadValue
        elif currentLineReadName="b\'HumidityB":
            HumidityB=currentLineReadValue
        elif currentLineReadName="b\'pHvalue":
            pHvalue=currentLineReadValue
        elif currentLineReadName="b\'extractorstatement":
            extractorStatement=currentLineReadValue
        elif currentLineReadName="b\'lightstatement":
            ligthStatement=currentLineReadValue
        elif currentLineReadName="b\'intractorstatement":
            intractorStatement=currentLineReadValue
        else currentLineReadName="b'FANstatement":
            fanStatement=currentLineReadValue
        return(analogValue, VoltageEcSensor, tempWaterSensor, EcSensorValue, TemperatureB, HumidityB, pHvalue, extractorStatement, ligthStatement, intractorStatement, fanStatement)
```

here you have the output from the arduino, call 'currentLineRead' (vision of multiple line:

```py
b'
b'
b'Analog value:30\r\n'
b'Voltage:146\r\n'
b'temp:24.25\r\n'
b'EC:No solution!\r\n'
b'TemperatureB:23.60\r\n'
b'HumidityB:35.70\r\n'
b'pHvalue:14.68\r\n'
b'extractorstatement:1\r\n'
b'lightstatement:0\r\n'
b'intractorstatement:0\r\n'
b'FANstatement:10:0:0 1/1/0 Day_of_week:1\r\n'
b'
b'
b'Analog value:30\r\n'
b'Voltage:146\r\n'
b'temp:24.25\r\n'
b'EC:No solution!\r\n'
b'TemperatureB:23.60\r\n'
b'HumidityB:35.70\r\n'
b'pHvalue:14.68\r\n'
b'extractorstatement:1\r\n'
b'lightstatement:0\r\n'
b'intractorstatement:0\r\n'
b'FANstatement:10:0:0 1/1/0 Day_of_week:1\r\n
```

I want to attribut each value into the variable set above. For instance : b'TemperatureB:23.60\r\n', I want just want the numerical value. What is the best way to do it please ?

thanks !

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
This is a matter of using string functions to extract the desired information from your input.  Look up how to find text between two text tags.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I want to attribute each value into variable"? What variable?

Comment: You can call `.strip()` on the *reading* to remove the trailing newline and then use `.split(":",1)` to get the key/value pair.

Comment: @Prune Sorry about that I have correct my post.

Comment: @ acw1668 Thanks for your your respons

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"doesn't work" is not a problem specification.  Your posted output shows no attempt to parse the line.  Your code is not minimal.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use the json package and some snipped I found [here](https://gist.github.com/simon-engledew/26e2b0030278d2b5f60ede176e6c5fe8) to "relax" the syntax to not require " " quotation marks around keys, (since  ArduinoJson sends strings with that standardization to save some bytes during transfer)

Deserializing your json lines as a python dictionnary object, is probably the best way to go.
It allows you to :

- get the value of a key easily by name
- test if the key it exists

All that just by calling the `.get("key_name")` method that by default returns `None` if no key with the name `"key_name"` is in your dictionnary.

Here is the snippet :

Classes and objects declarations

```
import re
import json
from parsec import (
    sepBy,
    regex,
    string,
    generate,
    many
)

whitespace = regex(r'\s*', re.MULTILINE)

lexeme = lambda p: p << whitespace

lbrace = lexeme(string('{'))
rbrace = lexeme(string('}'))
lbrack = lexeme(string('['))
rbrack = lexeme(string(']'))
colon = lexeme(string(':'))
comma = lexeme(string(','))
true = lexeme(string('true')).result(True)
false = lexeme(string('false')).result(False)
null = lexeme(string('null')).result(None)
quote = string('"') | string("'")

def number():
    return lexeme(
        regex(r'-?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)([.][0-9]+)?([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?')
    ).parsecmap(float)


def charseq():
    def string_part():
        return regex(r'[^"\'\\]+')

    def string_esc():
        return string('\\') >> (
            string('\\')
            | string('/')
            | string('b').result('\b')
            | string('f').result('\f')
            | string('n').result('\n')
            | string('r').result('\r')
            | string('t').result('\t')
            | regex(r'u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}').parsecmap(lambda s: chr(int(s[1:], 16)))
            | quote
        )
    return string_part() | string_esc()

class StopGenerator(StopIteration):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

@lexeme
@generate
def quoted():
    yield quote
    body = yield many(charseq())
    yield quote
    raise StopGenerator(''.join(body))

@generate
def array():
    yield lbrack
    elements = yield sepBy(value, comma)
    yield rbrack
    raise StopGenerator(elements)


@generate
def object_pair():
    key = yield regex(r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*') | quoted
    yield colon
    val = yield value
    raise StopGenerator((key, val))


@generate
def json_object():
    yield lbrace
    pairs = yield sepBy(object_pair, comma)
    yield rbrace
    raise StopGenerator(dict(pairs))
    
value = quoted | number() | json_object | array | true | false | null
relaxed_json = whitespace >> json_object
```

And here is the way to use it easily :

```
input_byte = b'{test:157}' # Placeholder for a line you recieved as bytes 
input_dict = relaxed_json.parse(input_byte.decode()) #decode to a string
# then parse it with json package to get a dictionnary

print(input_dict) # here is it's content printed
print(type(input_dict)) # it is a dictionnary
print(input_dict.get("test",None)) # You can get the value of a key...
print(input_dict.get("toast",None)) # and test if it exists with one same method
if input_dict.get("toast",None) is not None: #if it exists you can use it
    print("Toast key has value :",input_dict.get("toast"))
else : #if it doesn't exist in your dict, in that case .get() methods returns None, and you can do something else
    print("No key named toast here")
```

Outputs :

```
{'test': 157.0}
<class 'dict'>
157.0
None
No key named toast here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have parse the data from arduino output in other form to be able to use it. But Your way seem to be more useful as I do. I will try it.